# How can i use javascript to insert text into a textarea?

Tags: javascript, text

I need to insert some text into a textarea at the place where the cursor is, how can i do this without jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check the small code sample at:

- [Inserting at the cursor using JavaScript](http://alexking.org/blog/2003/06/02/inserting-at-the-cursor-using-javascript)

Code from the above article:

```
function insertAtCursor(myField, myValue) {

  if (document.selection) {
    myField.focus();
    sel = document.selection.createRange();
    sel.text = myValue;
  }
  else if (myField.selectionStart || myField.selectionStart == '0') {
    var startPos = myField.selectionStart;
    var endPos = myField.selectionEnd;

    myField.value = myField.value.substring(0, startPos)
                  + myValue
                  + myField.value.substring(endPos, myField.value.length);
  } else {
    myField.value += myValue;
  }
}

// calling the function
insertAtCursor(document.getElementById('textarea_id'), 'sometext');
```

Comment: i want to insert text into the middle, not replace the thing

Comment: Modified. Tested the above in Firefox.

Comment: Nice find.  +1 for including both the source of your info in addition to the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Use an HTML `title` attribute? That will place tooltip text next to the cursor when it's over a particular element.

Or you could create a `<div>` with `position: fixed`, then position it at `event.screenX, event.screenY`:

```
<div id="tip" style="position: fixed; visibility: hidden;"></div>
<textarea onmousemove="position();" onmouseout="hide();"></texarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function position() {
    var d = document.getElementById('tip');
    d.style.visibility = 'visible';
    d.style.left = event.screenX + 'px';
    d.style.top = event.screenX + 'py';
  }
  function hide() {
    document.getElementById('tip').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this person](http://parentnode.org/javascript/working-with-the-cursor-position/)'s code [here](http://pastebin.parentnode.org/78). This code uses the `selection` property of the `document` object to get the cursor position, and then builds a new string and stuffs it into the textarea. It also has a specialized routine for IE which has much more cumbersome logic for finding the cursor position.