# How to insert text into a textarea using JavaScript without messing up edit history?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, undo-redo

Basically what i want is if a user selects some text in a textarea and presses ctrl + b then the text within the selection should be surrounded by stars.

so basically what I want is :

> 1) textarea content : "hello this is some text"
>
> 2) user selects some text and presses ctrl + b "hello this **is some** text" (assume the bolded part is a text selection)
>
> 3) so I want the textarea content to be :
>         "hello this *is some* text"
>
> 4) and if the user presses ctrl + z(or whatever the undo action) the
>   textarea content should go back to being "hello this is some text"

I have tried [How can i use javascript to insert text into a textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204580/how-can-i-use-javascript-to-insert-text-into-a-textarea) and [Insert text into textarea at cursor position (Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076975/insert-text-into-textarea-at-cursor-position-javascript) and similar but the issue is that on doing undo (ctrl + z) for most browsers I expect the text to go back to go to the value in step 1. but this does not happen. I understand stackoverflow implements own undo redo functionality in its editor. but I was hoping not to go to that much complexity.
Have to support chrome and safari

An approach I am thinking about would be to position the cursor and issue a synthetic key event. I don't know if it will work and if it would be free of issues

Comment: The answers below suggest `execCommand` which is deprecated. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/60581285/1066234 – Probably one way would be to track the edit states by yourself (in HTML5's localstorage) and load the former state of the textarea with each CTRL Z.

Comment: Or you use a global JS variable to store the different states. For example, SCEditor does it like this with the [undo.js](https://github.com/samclarke/SCEditor/blob/master/src/plugins/undo.js) plugin, see `var undoStates = [];` and `function storeState()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Updated Version

To save user history when changing a textarea's overall value, instead of:

```
textarea.value = newText;
```

Use:

```
textarea.focus();
document.execCommand('selectAll',false);

var el = document.createElement('p');
el.innerText = newText;

document.execCommand('insertHTML',false,el.innerHTML);
```

It takes about **~1 second** on my mid-end gaming rig with a string a little over 4,000 characters, so you'll have to figure out if that's acceptable for your use case.

### Old Version

Maybe you're familiar with `execCommand` and wonder why we don't just use this:

```
textarea.focus();
document.execCommand('selectAll',false);
document.execCommand('insertText',false,newText);
```

On Chromium `insertText` is *extremely* slow, especially for longer strings. For an example over 4,000 characters, on my mid-gaming compy the same string as used in the Updated Version takes **~10 seconds**.

It *does* save user history too though, and moving between history states is still an acceptable speed (~0.5 seconds).

Does it make sense that this is slower, since I would assume what I'm doing explicitly in the Updated Version Chromium's doing in the background anyway? No. But this is where Chromium's at today, I guess. Comment below if the Old Version becomes better.

### General Notes

Unfortunately, `execCommand` doesn't work inside of textarea elements in Firefox. [This may be fixed in an upcoming version.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1220696)

Tested in Chromium and Firefox.

If I find a still faster solution (and/or one that works in Firefox), I will definitely share it.

Comment: Interesting, if you use `insertHTML` instead of `insertText`, it runs much faster. However, if anything could be read as HTML, it will be cut out. I'll do further testing.

Comment: I have also experienced that `execCommand("insertText")` with Chrome (not with Firefox) is extremely slow (I use a *contenteditable pre*). Your solution makes it better. The bottleneck is then the `el.innerText = newText`. This can be made faster with `el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newText))`

Answer (score 2):

I got the below code from: http://www.javascriptsource.com/forms/undo-redo.html and you can check its working example as well.
Though you might need to implement your own functionalities such as Bold, Italic etc.

```js
function iObject() {
  this.i;
  return this;
}

var myObject=new iObject();
myObject.i=0;
var myObject2=new iObject();
myObject2.i=0;
store_text=new Array();

//store_text[0] store initial textarea value
store_text[0]="";

function countclik(tag) {
  myObject.i++;
  var y=myObject.i;
  var x=tag.value;
  store_text[y]=x;
}

function undo(tag) {
  if ((myObject2.i)<(myObject.i)) {
    myObject2.i++;
  } else {
    alert("Finish Undo Action");
  }
  var z=store_text.length;
  z=z-myObject2.i;
  if (store_text[z]) {
   tag.value=store_text[z];
  } else {
   tag.value=store_text[0];
  }
}

function redo(tag) {
  if((myObject2.i)>1) {
    myObject2.i--;
  } else {
    alert("Finish Redo Action");
  }
  var z=store_text.length;
  z=z-myObject2.i;
  if (store_text[z]) {
    tag.value=store_text[z];
  } else {
  tag.value=store_text[0];
  }
 }
```

```html
<form name=form1>
  <input type="button"  class="red" value="Undo" onmousedown="undo(document.form1.text1);">
  <input type="button" class="red" value="Redo" onmousedown="redo(document.form1.text1);">
  <br>
  <textarea rows=7 cols=50  name=text1 onkeydown="countclik(document.form1.text1);" >
  </textarea>
</form>


<p><center>
<font face="arial, helvetica" size"-2">Free JavaScripts provided<br>
by <a href="http://javascriptsource.com">The JavaScript Source</a></font>
</center><p>
```

I have used [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) in the past and would recommend to use it. You could also use [niceditor](http://nicedit.com/)

Comment: well thanks for the answer :) . but as I mentioned in the question I was hoping to do this without resorting to building own undo redo functionality :)

Comment: You could use plugins such as ckeditor, I believe it would cut down a lot of your work when it comes to adding in functionalities :)